# R error: Coercing 'list' RHS to 'double' to match the type of the target column

Tags: r, data.table

I have a dataset DT as below:

- All date columns are 'date'
- All res columns are 'numeric'
- date_1 and res_1 are pair and date_2 and res_2 are pair

```
    index_date  date_1      date_2      res_1   res_2   taken_date   taken_res
1   2015-08-25  2013-11-13  2015-08-25  1.50    1.5     NA           NA
2   2017-09-11  2016-09-29  2017-05-12  2.70    2.4     NA           NA
3   2015-08-17  2014-08-08  2015-06-08  2.00    2.6     NA           NA
4   2017-05-14  2016-05-31  2016-12-19  1.30    1.2     NA           NA
5   2015-11-14  2014-11-11  2015-08-10  1.60    2.8     NA           NA
6   2016-08-08  NA          2016-08-08  NA      1.4     NA           NA
7   2018-12-01  2014-05-30  2017-07-24  1.70    1.8     NA           NA
8   2013-01-11  NA          2012-10-23  NA      3.7     NA           NA
9   2015-06-06  NA          2015-02-07  NA      1.3     NA           NA
10  2015-05-19  NA          2015-05-19  NA      1.4     NA           NA
```

What I want:

- Filling values in "taken_date" and "taken_res" by comparing "date_1" and "date_2" with "index_date"
- "taken_date" and "taken_res" will be the closest date and result to the "index_date"
- For example, the first row should be *2015-08-25* for "taken_date" and *1.5* for "taken_res"

I have a working function, which finds the closest date and fill values accordingly, if there are two dates and results.

However, my issue comes when there is only one date and result, like the 6th, 8th, 9th, and 10th.

The code is:

```
date.vars <- c("date_1", "date_2")
res.vars <- c("res_1", "res_2")
taken.vars <- c("taken_date", "taken_res")

# some more lines here to prepare DT
...

# only one date and result
DT[apply(DT[, date.vars, with=F], 1, function(x)
  sum(is.na(x))==1), 

  (taken.vars) := list(
    apply(.SD, 1, function(x)
      as.numeric(na.omit(x[res.vars]))),

    apply(.SD, 1, function(x)
      as.Date(na.omit(x[date.vars])))
  )]
```

R returns me warning as below:

```
Error in `[.data.table`(DT, apply(DT[, date.vars, with = F], 1, function(x) sum(is.na(x)) ==  : 
  (list) object cannot be coerced to type 'double'
In addition: Warning message:
In `[.data.table`(DT, apply(DT[, date.vars, with = F], 1, function(x) sum(is.na(x)) ==  :
  Coercing 'list' RHS to 'double' to match the type of the target column (column 7 named 'taken_res').
```

Would you please help me to correct my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my attempt. I did not handle the cases where there is NA in date. What you can do is to calculate the gaps between 1) index date and date 1, and 2) index date and date 2. Using the gaps, you can run logical checks. Based on that, you can assign targeted dates and values.

I am not the right person who can explain the error message well. But, I think you are facing coercion issues. See page 16 in the CRAN manual (version 1.12.8), where you can find information on `:=` (assignment by reference). If anybody can provide technical explanation, please do so.

```
setDT(mydt)[, `:=` (taken_date = fifelse(test = abs(index_date - date_1) < abs(index_date - date_2),
                                         yes = date_1,
                                         no = date_2),
                    taken_res = fifelse(test = abs(index_date - date_1) < abs(index_date - date_2),
                                        yes = res_1,
                                        no = res_2))][]

#    index_date     date_1     date_2 res_1 res_2 taken_date taken_res
# 1: 2015-08-25 2013-11-13 2015-08-25   1.5   1.5 2015-08-25       1.5
# 2: 2017-09-11 2016-09-29 2017-05-12   2.7   2.4 2017-05-12       2.4
# 3: 2015-08-17 2014-08-08 2015-06-08   2.0   2.6 2015-06-08       2.6
# 4: 2017-05-14 2016-05-31 2016-12-19   1.3   1.2 2016-12-19       1.2
# 5: 2015-11-14 2014-11-11 2015-08-10   1.6   2.8 2015-08-10       2.8
# 6: 2016-08-08       <NA> 2016-08-08    NA   1.4       <NA>        NA
# 7: 2018-12-01 2014-05-30 2017-07-24   1.7   1.8 2017-07-24       1.8
# 8: 2013-01-11       <NA> 2012-10-23    NA   3.7       <NA>        NA
# 9: 2015-06-06       <NA> 2015-02-07    NA   1.3       <NA>        NA
#10: 2015-05-19       <NA> 2015-05-19    NA   1.4       <NA>        NA
```

Although you have not clearly mentioned what you wanna do with rows with NA, it seems to me that you were trying to do something like this.

```
setDT(mydt)[, `:=` (taken_date = fifelse(test = abs(index_date - date_1) < abs(index_date - date_2),
                                         yes = date_1,
                                         no = date_2),
                    taken_res = fifelse(test = abs(index_date - date_1) < abs(index_date - date_2),
                                        yes = res_1,
                                        no = res_2))][is.na(date_1),
            `:=` (taken_date = date_2, taken_res = res_2)][is.na(date_2),
            `:=` (taken_date = date_1, taken_res = res_1)]

#    index_date     date_1     date_2 res_1 res_2 taken_date taken_res
# 1: 2015-08-25 2013-11-13 2015-08-25   1.5   1.5 2015-08-25       1.5
# 2: 2017-09-11 2016-09-29 2017-05-12   2.7   2.4 2017-05-12       2.4
# 3: 2015-08-17 2014-08-08 2015-06-08   2.0   2.6 2015-06-08       2.6
# 4: 2017-05-14 2016-05-31 2016-12-19   1.3   1.2 2016-12-19       1.2
# 5: 2015-11-14 2014-11-11 2015-08-10   1.6   2.8 2015-08-10       2.8
# 6: 2016-08-08       <NA> 2016-08-08    NA   1.4 2016-08-08       1.4
# 7: 2018-12-01 2014-05-30 2017-07-24   1.7   1.8 2017-07-24       1.8
# 8: 2013-01-11       <NA> 2012-10-23    NA   3.7 2012-10-23       3.7
# 9: 2015-06-06       <NA> 2015-02-07    NA   1.3 2015-02-07       1.3
#10: 2015-05-19       <NA> 2015-05-19    NA   1.4 2015-05-19       1.4
```

**DATA**

```
mydt <- structure(list(index_date = structure(c(16672, 17420, 16664, 
17300, 16753, 17021, 17866, 15716, 16592, 16574), class = "Date"), 
date_1 = structure(c(16022, 17073, 16290, 16952, 16385, NA, 
16220, NA, NA, NA), class = "Date"), date_2 = structure(c(16672, 
17298, 16594, 17154, 16657, 17021, 17371, 15636, 16473, 16574
), class = "Date"), res_1 = c(1.5, 2.7, 2, 1.3, 1.6, NA, 
1.7, NA, NA, NA), res_2 = c(1.5, 2.4, 2.6, 1.2, 2.8, 1.4, 
1.8, 3.7, 1.3, 1.4)), row.names = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", 
"6", "7", "8", "9", "10"), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Nice use of `fifelse`

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However my issue is when there is NA in date.

Comment: @akrun Thank you. I have been studying data.table again, and I thought this was a good chance to use it.

Comment: @ikryong I see. Can you describe what you want to do? As far as I see, you did not describe cases with NA in your question.

Comment: @ikryong You have not mentioned anything further. But it seems to me that, when you either date_1 or date_2  is NA, you want to assign date and res that have values. If so, what I update will help you.

Comment: @jazzrro Thank you so much. I was caught up with other things so I could not checked it since yesterday. Yes your update seems helping me a lot. I will try your method and let you know how it goes!

Comment: @jazzurro It works perfectly well. Thank you so much!

Comment: @ikryong I am glad to hear that. Aso for your code, you were trying to create two columns. It seems that you made data.table add two cells in each row. But that is not how data.table is working. data.table is create one column each. You were creating date and number together; date and numeric values were mixed up in one column, I guess. As far as I can see, perhaps that was what was going on.